# Electron - How to enforce minimum window size even when the Dev Tools is open

Tags: electron

I have set the minimum width and height for my Electron application so that I don't need to care about media queries for smaller sizes, but if users open the Dev Tools, the minimum width and height is applied to the outer window's size so subtracting the Dev Tools size, the real display size for my application can be much smaller and the UI will be broken. Is there any way to apply the minimum width and height to the real content of the Electron app, not including the Dev Tools?

Comment: Why dont you prevent user toggling devtool instead? I think let user open devtool is not a good idea.

Comment: I will consider it, but this is not what I can decide on my own so let's just assume that we still need to enable the Dev Tools, I would like to know if there is any way to do that

Comment: what do you actually expect? Should your window grow dynamically when you open devtools or what? Devtool is something you open to investigate things, not seeing a production view. Also you can *detach* devtools, so it won't interfere with your window size ( `openDevTools({ mode: 'detach' })` in 3.0+)